# Efficient javascript algorithm for choosing item from array where each entry has a different weight

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Basically i have a bi dimensional array in java script, in the form of object, probability:

A,10
B,50
C,20
D,20

where the number is the probablity out of 100 of that item to be chosen.

Whats the most efficient algo to randomly choose an item following the specified probabilities?

(At the moment i get a random number from 1-100 and choose one item based on the sum of the previous items, so 5 would get A, 40 B, 65 C, etc.)

thanks!

M

Comment: Can you show the exact structure of the data in proper javascript notation

Comment: For the record, there should be no language-dependent algorithm as it should be a generic solution to a problem.

Comment: if A is supposed to be 10%, B is 50% etc. then pick a random # 1-100 and if number is 1-10, that represents A. 11-61, that represents B, etc..

Comment: Andrue - agreed, its the algorithm I am after more than the actual language specifics.

Comment: Hi Crayon - yes this is what i am doing at the moment, but takes a lot of iterations / adding up etc - I am sure I am missing the obvious here.. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if efficiency is a concern here and your probabilities are integers, you could just create a lookup table like this:

```
// I assume the probabilities are in an object probs
// in the form { "A": 10, "B": 90 }

var lut = new Array(100);
var lutIndex = 0;
for (var key in probs) {
    for (var i=0 ; i<probs[key] ; i++) {
        lut[lutIndex] = key;
        lutIndex++;
    }
}

// now, you can get the random object -- represented by a letter -- like this
var randomObject = lut[randomNumber];
```

Comment: This won't work reliably because JavaScript objects are not ordered.

Comment: This was what I also thought at first. However, order doesn't matter at all in this case.

Comment: @torazaburo If there is a key "X" in probs with probability n, then it is only important that n indexes of the lut array contain "X". It is not important which indexes.

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume your input is in the form

```
var probs = [['A' ,10], ['B', 50], ['C', 20], ['D', 20]];
```

Calculate the cumulative probabilities:

```
var cur = 0;
var cumulative = probs.map(elt => cur += elt[1]);
```

That will create an array

```
[10, 60, 80, 100]
```

Write a function to find which element corresponds to a particular probability:

```
function get_element(prob) {
  for (var i = 0; i < cumulative.length; i++) {
    if (prob <= cumulative[i]) return i;
  }
}
```

Now just write

```
probs[get_element(Math.random() * 100)] [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a lookup table, you can quickly determine the object like this:

```
// I assume the probabilities are in an object probs
// in the form { "A": 10, "B": 90 }

function getObjectForRandomInt(i) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var key in probs) {
        if (i <= sum) return key;
        sum += probs[key];
    }
}
```

Note that it is not important in which order the keys of `probs` are traversed (object fields are unordered in javascript)! Even if the order changes every time, it still works as it should. If you are not convinced, imagine you could force a certain order to skew the results. Without knowing the next random int `i` in advance this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered a pretty awesome solution to this exact problem a few weeks ago. There is a method called the [*alias method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method) which sets up in O(n) and runs in O(1) by creating a pair of arrays that turns each of your arbitrary probability choices into an array of biased coins. My JavaScript implementation is below:

```
function generate_random_selector(input_probabilities) {
    // Generates a random selector function using the Alias Method
    // for discrete probability distributions (see
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method for an explanation)
    var i = 0;
    var probabilities = [], aliases = [];
    var probSum = 0;

    // Fill the probabilities array
    // Slightly modify this call for your own input structure
    // If you need to return names instead of numbers, create
    // an indexed array of names during this step.
    input_probabilities.forEach(function(p) {
        probabilities.push(p);
        probSum += p;
    });

    // Normalize all probabilities to average to 1
    // and categorize each probability as to where it fits
    // in that scale
    var probMultiplier = probabilities.length / probSum;
    var overFull = [], underFull = [];
    probabilities = probabilities.map(function(p, i) {
        var newP = p * probMultiplier;
        if (newP > 1) overFull.push(i);
        else if (newP < 1) underFull.push(i);
        else if (newP !== 1) {
            throw "Non-numerical value got into probabilities";
        }
        return newP;
    });
    overFull.sort();
    underFull.sort();

    // Process both queues by having each under-full entry
    // have the rest of its space occupied by the fullest
    // over-full entry, re-categorizing the over-full entry
    // as needed
    while (overFull.length > 0 || underFull.length > 0) {
        if (!(overFull.length > 0 && underFull.length > 0)) {
            // only reached due to rounding errors.
            // Just assign all the remaining probabilities to 1
            var notEmptyArray = overFull.length > 0 ? overFull : underFull;
            notEmptyArray.forEach(function(index) {
                probabilities[index] = 1;
            });
            break; // get out of the while loop
        }

        aliases[underFull[0]] = overFull[0];
        probabilities[overFull[0]] += probabilities[underFull[0]] - 1;
        underFull.shift();
        if (probabilities[overFull[0]] > 1) overFull.push(overFull.shift());
        else if (probabilities[overFull[0]] < 1) underFull.push(overFull.shift());
        else overFull.shift();
    }

    return function() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * probabilities.length);
        // If you need to return a name and created an LUT during
        // the preparation code, set the index attained below
        // to a variable and return lut[index];
        return Math.random() < probabilities[index] ? index : aliases[index];
    }
}

var selector = generate_random_selector([10, 50, 20, 20]);
var sample = selector();
```

Here's how it works:

1. Each time the selector runs, it starts by picking a random index with uniform probability.
2. Then, it rolls a random number between 0 and 1 and compares it to the probability in that index.
3. If the rolled number is less than the probability, it returns that index.
4. Otherwise, the selector consults a matching table, called the *alias table*, and returns the entry found for that index. This entry corresponds to another item in the table.

To build these two tables, we do the following:

1. We scale each of the probabilities so that the average probability among all of the items is 1. As we do so, we separate each item into "over full", "under full", and "exactly full" categories depending on whether the scaled probability is greater than, less than, or equal to 1.
2. We then take one item from the "over full" category and one from the "under full" category.
3. We then assign the extra space in the "under full" item to the "over full" item by setting the *alias* of the "under full" item to the "over full" item's index, then subtracting the space just filled from the overfull item's probability. The previously "under full" item is now exactly full, since it is a biased coin with itself as one side and the "over full" item as the other side.
4. After this, we re-queue the "over full" item into its appropriate category, as in step 1.
5. We repeat steps 2-4 until all items are exactly full.

This algorithm runs in O(n) time and is always guaranteed to terminate properly using arbitrary precision decimal numbers - each iteration puts at least one item into the exactly full category and the last one puts in both. If one of the categories empties before the other, it's due to small rounding errors and you can still get strong results by setting the remaining probabilities to 1.

And probably the best part is that it does the scaling *for you*. You can have any number of elements like this of pretty much any precision (including real number precision), and they don't even have to add up to 1 or 100 or whatever else when you get them.